# Java http download corrupts file

Tags: java, http, download

I have a problem, which I do not seem to be able to solve...
I do a http download of a file, but the CRC32 of the file on the server and on the client do not match. Also, the file has different size, so obviously I must be doing something wrong... when I download via Firefox, the filesize is ok... so I guess it is somewhere in the client code.

I already found [Corrupt file when using Java to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401748/corrupt-file-when-using-java-to-download-file), but that didn't help me either...

Here's the code:

```
private void downloadJar(String fileName, long crc32Server) throws IOException {
  System.out.println("Downloading file '" + fileName + "' from server '" + mServer + "'.");
  HttpURLConnection sourceConnection = null;
  BufferedInputStream inputStream = null;
  BufferedWriter fileWriter = null;
  long crc32Client;
  try {
    URL sourceURL = new URL(fileName);
    try {
      sourceConnection = (HttpURLConnection)sourceURL.openConnection();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Configured URL caused a MalformedURLException: ", exc);
    }
    sourceConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "zip, jar");
    sourceConnection.connect();
    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(sourceConnection.getInputStream());
    fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(targetFolder + File.separator + fileName));
    CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
    for (int singleByte = inputStream.read(); singleByte != -1; singleByte = inputStream.read()) {
      fileWriter.write(singleByte);
      crc32.update(singleByte);
    }
    crc32Client = crc32.getValue();
  }
  finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
      inputStream.close();
    }
    if (fileWriter != null) {
      fileWriter.flush();
      fileWriter.close();
    }
    if (sourceConnection != null) {
      sourceConnection.disconnect();
    }
  }
  if (crc32Client != crc32Server) {
    //      deleteFile(fileName);
    throw new IOException("CRC32 did not match for file '" + fileName + "': " + crc32Client + "!="
        + crc32Server);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably get more responses if you don't make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [BufferedOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) instead of a [`FileWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)/[`BufferedWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). In general, `*Streams` handle raw binary data, while `*Writers` handle character data (which is an interpretation of the raw binary data for a given character encoding).

Comment: Now I get at least the same file size, thank you for the tipp. But the CRC check still fails...

Comment: Does the Firefox download give the same CRC32?

Comment: Seems to be a problem of different CRC32 calculations, the downloaded file is now binary identical to the one on the server...
Thanks for the help so far. I guess now I am on the road again ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid so... there are a bunch of CRC32 formulas. Maybe you could try MD5 or some other cryptographic hash instead.

Comment: I got it. I use CRC32 Java Std-Implementation. But when I created the CRC32 on the server, I did the same Stream/Writer mistake... causing different CRC32 as a result! Thanks a lot, I guess I wouldn't have found that easily...